# C array pointer maths. Have memory violation on access by index

Tags: c, arrays, visual-c++

I havent used C for 30 yrs.. so I apologise for a noob question. but i cant get whats wrong.

I allocate space for 3x3 matrix.

then I want to access it using array index and get memory violation.

```
double **m = (double **)malloc(3 * 3 * sizeof(double));
m[0][0] = 2; <-- exception
```

is it something wrong with my pointers arithmetic or is it something new in VC++ compiler? will it behave differently if I use another compiler?

EDIT : I read a lot of 'read only memory' remarks on inet.. since when we get it? can I switch it off?

Comment: m is definitely not null.. i can see address allocated in debugger

Comment: `double (*m)[3] = malloc(3 * 3 * sizeof(double));`

Comment: Note that you should NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3488231

Comment: @BLUEPIXY if you could put your comment as answer and explain why cant i access memory using double **. I will mark it as the answer..

Comment: C != C++ (i.e. don't cast `malloc` in C, use container classes in C++).

Comment: when `double **m` then `m[0]` is `double *` but it isn't.

Comment: It looks to me like `m` should be declared as `double *m` because `malloc(3 * 3 * sizeof(double))` allocates a single-dimensional array of `double`, not an array of pointers to `double`. If you want to access row 1, column 2 of what you're viewing as a 2-d array you'd use something like `m[(1 * 3) + 2]` as the index.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `double (*m)[3] = malloc( 3 * sizeof *m )` would be even better.

Comment: @JohnBode Immaterial.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Not at all -- it's cleaner and reduces maintenance headaches if the number of columns needs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` returns `void*`. But you are using the result as an array of pointers.

If you are going to allocate the whole matrix continously then you should access each element with the following code:

```
m[ROW*columns + COLUMN] = 2;
```

where `m` is defined as:

```
double *m = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 4):

You only allocate memory for `m` (with the wrong size), not `m[0]`, `m[1]` and `m[2]`.

```
double **m = malloc(3 * sizeof(double *));
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    m[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
}
```

Remember to free all of them when they are not used.

Comment: thanks. question though - if a pointer is 8 byte and each double is 8 byte.. how much memory exactly i am going to use after running your code? is it 3x3 double + 4 poiners (m + 3 pointers to each row)?

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating enough space, you need to allocate space for 3 pointers of `double` and 9 `doubles`, and you was allocating only for 9 `double`s.

The following should work

```
double **m = malloc(3 * sizeof(double *));

m[0] = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
m[1] = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
m[2] = malloc(3 * sizeof(double));

m[0][0] = 2.0;
```

you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` since in c, `void *` is automatically converted to any type of pointer. Also if your matrix is  `n`×`n` you can use a `for (i = 0 ; i < n ; ++1)` loop.

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT NOTE UP FRONT**

If this is meant to be compiled as C code, make sure your compiler is actually compiling it *as C*, not C++, otherwise the code I've written below won't work.

If this is meant to be compiled as C++, use `new` instead of `malloc` (or better yet, use vectors)

If this is meant to be compiled as either C or C++, then create an abstraction layer and use `malloc` for the C implementation and `new` for the C++ implementation.

Now that we've gotten that out of the way...

Let's start from the other end.  Suppose you declare a 3x3 matrix as

```
double m[3][3];
```

Remember that unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So, the type of the expression `m[i][j]` is `double` (duh).  The type of the expression `m[i]` is "3-element array of `double`", or `double [3]`; unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will decay to an expression of type "pointer to `double`", or `double *`.

Now for the tricky bit: the type of the expression `m` is "3-element array of 3-element array of `double`", or `double [3][3]`; unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will decay to an expression of type "pointer to 3-element array of `double`", or `double (*)[3]`, *not* `double **`.  So if you want to allocate a 3x3 matrix dynamically, you want the type of `m` to be `double (*)[3]`, not `double **`:

```
double (*m)[3] = malloc( 3 * sizeof *m );
```

The type of the expression `*m` is "3-element array of `double`", so `sizeof *m == sizeof (double [3]) == 3 * sizeof (double)`.

When you allocated memory as

```
double **m = malloc( 3 * 3 * sizeof (double));
```

you allocated a *single-dimensioned array of pointers to `double`*, but you set aside the wrong amount of memory, and each element of the array contained an *indeterminate* pointer value, which is why writing to `m[0][0]` threw an exception.  You would have to allocate such an array in 2 stages:

```
double **m = malloc( 3 * sizeof *m ); // allocates space for 3 pointers to double
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  m[i] = malloc( 3 * sizeof *m[i]);   // allocates space for 3 doubles
```

If you need the memory to be contiguous, use the first method.  If the memory doesn't have to be contiguous, you can use the second method.

Generalizing this to NxM matrices:

If you know the number of rows and columns at compile time and the memory must be contiguous, use the following:

```
T (*m)[COLS] = malloc( ROWS * sizeof *m );
```

If you *don't* know the number of rows and columns at compile time and you are using a C99 compiler or a C 2011 compiler that supports variable-length arrays, use the following:

```
size_t rows, cols;
rows = get_rows();
cols = get_cols();
T (*m)[cols] = malloc( rows * sizeof *m );
```

If you don't know the number of rows and columns at compile time and variable-length arrays aren't available, *or* the matrix is so large that you cannot allocate it as a single, contiguous block, use the following:

```
T **m = malloc( rows * sizeof *m );
if ( m )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  {
    m[i] = malloc( cols * sizeof *m[i] );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `double **` does not correspond to the pointer to first element of a two-dimensional array.

The correct code will look like

```
double( *m )[3] = double ( * )[3] malloc( 3 * 3 * sizeof( double ) );
m[0][0] = 2;
```

And for to free the array you could write

```
free( m );
```

As for type `double **` then it might be a pointer to first element of a one-dimensional array that has type `double * [3]`

For example

```
double **m = ( double ** )malloc( 3 * sizeof( double * ) );
```

In this case that to initialize each element of the array with a pointer to an allocated memory you should use a loop. For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) m[i] = malloc( 3 * sizeof( double ) );
```

For it would be more clear consider the following declarations

```
double a1[3][3];
double ( *pa1 )[3] = a1;

double * a2[3];
double **pa2 = a2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a 3x3 matrix, you can keep it on the stack:

```
double m[3][3];
m[0][0]=2.0;
```